# Duplication of actions in acumatica

Tags: c#, acumatica

Hi all i have a simple question for me a newbie on acumatica development i have a custom grid that i made and i referenced it to my custom dac then this happen i have two insert and two delete action button how can i resolve this issue [image]

so here is the screen shot then here is my code

```
[Serializable]
  public class withholdingtax : IBqlTable
  {
    #region Idnbr
    [PXDBIdentity]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Idnbr")]
    public virtual int? Idnbr { get; set; }
    public abstract class idnbr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<idnbr> { }
    #endregion

    #region Atc
    [PXDBString(50, InputMask = "", IsKey = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Atc")]
    public virtual string Atc { get; set; }
    public abstract class atc : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<atc> { }
    #endregion

    #region Type
    [PXDBString(50, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Type")]
    public virtual string Type { get; set; }
    public abstract class type : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<type> { }
    #endregion

    #region Description
    [PXDBString(InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Description")]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public abstract class description : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<description> { }
    #endregion

    #region TaxRate
    [PXDBString(50, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Tax Rate")]
    public virtual string TaxRate { get; set; }
    public abstract class taxRate : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<taxRate> { }
    #endregion

    #region Bir_form
    [PXDBString(50, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Bir_form")]
    public virtual string Bir_form { get; set; }
    public abstract class bir_form : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<bir_form> { }
    #endregion
  }
```

then this is my code to get this custom dac

```
 public class WithHolding : PXGraph<WithHolding, withholdingtax>
    {


        public PXSelect<withholdingtax> MasterView;
```

how did i get two of insert and two of delete i made sure that the primary view is masterview then the grid datamember is masterview also.

this is a template of a grid on acumatica create new custom screen thank you for your answer
UPDATE: Here is my aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/ListView.master" AutoEventWireup="true" ValidateRequest="false" CodeFile="WT100000.aspx.cs" Inherits="Page_WT100000" Title="Untitled Page" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPages/ListView.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="cont1" ContentPlaceHolderID="phDS" Runat="Server">
  <px:PXDataSource ID="ds" runat="server" Visible="True" Width="100%"
        TypeName="CloudianGlobal12.WithHolding"
        PrimaryView="MasterView"
        >
    <CallbackCommands>

    </CallbackCommands>
  </px:PXDataSource>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="cont2" ContentPlaceHolderID="phL" runat="Server">
  <px:PXGrid ID="grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Width="100%" Height="150px" SkinID="Primary" AllowAutoHide="false">
    <Levels>
      <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="MasterView">
          <Columns>
        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Idnbr" Width="70" />
        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Atc" Width="180" />
        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Type" Width="180" />
        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Description" Width="70" />
        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="TaxRate" Width="180" />
        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Bir_form" Width="180" /></Columns>
      </px:PXGridLevel>
    </Levels>
    <AutoSize Container="Window" Enabled="True" MinHeight="150" />
    <ActionBar >
    </ActionBar>
  </px:PXGrid>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: The extra action could have been added from the ASPX screen or the Graph. We need the full Graph and ASPX source file to troubleshoot this one.

Comment: Declaring the graph with second generic type 'withholdingtax' DAC will add a New Record/Insert button. In the graph or in ASPX there is likely another declaration that adds the second insert button, this one can be removed to resolve the issue.

Comment: Ok i will update my thread

Comment: Update: Hi @HB_ACUMATICA thank you for your help it worked when i removed the second generic type

Comment: The normal pattern is to keep the generic type but likely both will owrk. I believe the other button is coming from the SkinID. I will post an answer.">

Comment: I revised my answer, on second thought SkinID might be better when you have a Grid in the first container.

Answer (score 0):

For maintenance screens with a Form container on top, use the second generic type parameter of the graph to add the toolbar icons. This would be MyPrimaryDAC in the example below:

```
 public class MyGraph : PXGraph<MyGraph, MyPrimaryDAC>
```

I believe the other buttons are added by the grid `SkinID="Primary"` attribute value:

```
  <px:PXGrid ID="grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Width="100%" Height="150px" SkinID="Primary" AllowAutoHide="false>
```

For grid you could remove the second generic type and use the Primary SkinID to add the toolbar buttons.